# How to set UTF-8 charset in exim4?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, exim, ubuntu-14.04

Using Ubuntu server 14.04 how to set UTF-8 CHARSET? It's using now ANSI by default so i can't see cyrillic letters.

I am using non-split config mode, so i have 2 files in /etc/exim4:

- /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template
- /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf

Using exim4 only as send-mail server only.

Answer (score 6):

Exim4 is character set agnostic. It just provides the transport and delivery mechanism for your email.  It handles UTF-8 and a wide variety of other character sets.

Character set selection must be specified.  The content should specify utf-8 if it is using it.

A content-type header can be used to indicate utf-8 content:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
```

Headers containing utf-8 content should be appropriately prefixed and quoted:

```
From: =?utf-8?Q?Iceland=20Naturally?= <icelandnatural@gmail.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?q?People_vs=2E_Ebola_-_thousands_volunteering!?=
```

Which clients are you using and how are they configured.

Comment: Thanks, i am sending emails via cron using shell script. But on previous server it was sending in the right charset.

Comment: @Heiachi Check the default locale for your new server, possibly using a cron entry to run the command `locale`.  Also look at the raw content of a message to see what character set was used and how they where encoded.  Check the default encoding of your mail read as well.